# What is the best Fortran 77 IDE?

Tags: software-recommendation, programming, ide, fortran

I use Ubuntu 12.04. I need to do some coding with Fortran 77. I have'nt found any IDE for Fortran 77. What is the solution?

Answer (score 2):

Not a big fan of IDEs, and FORTRAN is kind of a niche (especially 77, you'll be in a world of pain, let me guess: engineering student?). I honestly believe in the "one tool for one job" mantra, and I think a decent text-editor + command line tools is the better choice.

That being said, IDEs are really helpful and I think [Photran](http://www.eclipse.org/photran/) is the best bet. You will have to install Eclipse 4.2 first.

TIP: Never install Eclipse from Ubuntu's software center, it's really old and won't work for your case. Install Eclipse from their website.

good luck

Answer (score 2):

I use **Ubuntu 14.04**. I think that even gedit recognises syntax of fortran77. I do not know if it is best but I use Geany (available on ubuntu software centre). And then gfortran (probably default in ubuntu) and mostly **fortran90**, but I hope it is similar for fortran77.

In **Geany** I think you have to specify (if it is not done automatically):

Menu: *build* > *set commands for build*

In opened window then:

button:____________command: (depending on your fortran compiler)

compile___________*gfortran -Wall -c "%f"*     (I think this make object file)

build_____________*gfortran -Wall -o "%e" "%f"* (this makes executable file)

run_______________*"./%e"*  (this runs executable file)

click OK.
It should work.

It is not straightforward, when you see it for the first time.

Comment: Thanks for the hint about gedit.

Answer (score 1):

There is a pretty good development system in WATCOM fortran77/c/c++.  The help group is now defunct but the stuff is still on line for free.